# Getting the top 25 items from a list in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv data file. The format is a follows:

[image: Example excerpt from the csv data file]

I need to produce a sorted list the top 25 countries from this file. The output I am looking for is China, Russia, France, Germany, Canada.

I am new to Python. I have looked at the questions on StackOverflow and various tutorials. I am finding stuff on how to read a file, write a file, etc., but I am not finding anything that can provide direction on how to manipulate the data to produce the top 25 countries from the list.

Comment: Top 25 by what criteria? How many countries in the file total?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: Are you just counting the number of times a country appears? Sounds like you want to load with the `csv` module, then count with `collections.Counter`, but we're not going to write the code for you.

Comment: @ShadowRanger  I am not asking anyone to write code for me. I am asking for direction. cvs module and collections.Counter, provides me with some direction. Thank you. Much appreciated.

Comment: It's great that you don't want us to write your code for you; you might be surprised by how many people _do_ expect us to do just that. However, I'm not sure what your specific question is. If you get stuck implementing ShadowRanger's suggestions, post your code attempt, explain what your code does that's different to what you expect, and we'll help you fix it.

Answer (score -1):

If your criteria it is how many times each country appears, you can isolate a list with the name of the countries and use the collection Counter, like this:

```
from collections import Counter
with open('countries.csv', 'r') as file:
  countries_list = [line.split(',')[-1] for line in file.read().split('\n')[1:-1]]
  countries = Counter(countries_list)
  print(countries)
```

> line.split(',')[-1] - Get the name of the country
>
> file.read().split('\n')[1:-1] - Separate the lines of the file and exclude the first (header) and the last (blank line after the last '\n')

Comment: Almost no CSV format can be reliably parsed with `.split(',')`, thanks to quoting, embedded newlines, etc. There's a module for this, please don't reinvent the wheel poorly.